# Move 4 NSMutableArray objects at the same time

Tags: iphone, arrays, image

I made a square out of image-views. Each of them is an `Object` of an `Array`.
If I touch the upper left corner, I want the middle of my image-square to be in the bottom left corner.

How can I do that?

Comment: You'll get more (and better) responses if your question title is more specific and you post more detail of exactly what you are trying to do and what you've tried so far including relevant sample code.

Comment: I know, i was at a cyber cafe thing and i had to type really fast... I knew this question would get a minus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your question is. I'll assume the following:

1. Your grid is a square with the dimension stored in `gridWidth`
2. Objects in the grid are stored in `gridArray` ordered from top left to bottom right
3. When a tap is detected in the upper left of an object in the grid, `userTappedObject:` is called
4. You have a function called `layoutGrid' that walks the array and sets the frame of each object

Example:

```
- (void)userTappedObject:(id)tappedObject
{
    NSUInteger indexOfBottomLeft = gridWidth * (gridWidth - 1);

    // to exchange the tapped object with the object in the bottom left corner
    NSUInteger indexOfTappedObject = [myMutableArray indexOfObject:tappedObject];
    [gridArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:indexOfTappedObject withObjectAtIndex:indexOfBottomLeft];

    // to move the tapped object to the bottom left corner, collapsing objects to the left
    // from the bottom left corner to make room
    [gridArray removeObject:tappedObject];
    [gridArray insertObject:tappedObject atIndex:indexOfBottomLeft];

    // layout the grid (this could animate changes if desired)
    [self layoutGrid];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think it's not what im looking for... sorry. Il give you that + anyways :D